# display images in scrollView don't scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have to display 2 images from API in flex column, and it have to scroll but the issu is that it don't scroll and images are incomplete ! this is my code:

```
    return (
            <View style={Styles.container}>
            {
              this.state.isLoading
          ?
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={Colors.mainYellow}/>
          :

          <View
            style={Styles.containerImg}
            contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
          >

            <View style={Styles.containerImg}>
              <Image source={{uri: 'link to API' + this.state.privilegeData.link1}}
                style={Styles.imageStyle}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.containerImg}>
              <Image source={{uri: 'link to API' + this.state.privilegeData.link2}}
                style={Styles.imageStyle}
              />
            </View>

          </View>
            }
            </View>
    );
```

and this is the code of styles:

```
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      },

      containerImg: {
        flex: 1,
      },

      containerAI: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: wp('100%'),
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      },

  containerImg: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',

    // borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'blue'
  },

      imageStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        width: wp('100%'),
      },
```

If I add resiMode to images, I have my images complete but streched, I want to keep the height of image and scroll it

So when I replace View tag (containerImg) with ScrollView I have a red screen without any image

Comment: Do you have to scroll through each image?

Comment: no scroll juste container of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to see an array of images with `scrolling`, you can wrap the image in a `scrollview`. Please refer to my example.

The height of the image should be raised so that it is '`contain`' so as not to damage the image quality by increasing it too wide.

```js
//This is an example code to understand Image//
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              'http://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample_img.png',
          }}
          style={{ width: 400, height: 400, margin: 16,resizeMode: 'contain' }}
        />
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              'http://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample_img.png',
          }}
          style={{ width: 400, height: 400, margin: 16,resizeMode: 'contain' }}
        />
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              'http://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/sample_img.png',
          }}
          style={{ width: 400, height: 400, margin: 16,resizeMode: 'contain' }}
        />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: thank you! This is what I did but I have not defined a width and height to Images